# Adding Function Calculated Column to List of Data Frames

Tags: r, dataframe, quantmod

I have started my R learning by using a loop with the `quantmod` package.  Essentially, I'm looping through a vector of stock symbols to download a csv of data from Yahoo, then applying the SMA (`sma10 <- SMA(data[c('Adj.Close')],n=10)` function to add a column to the data, before finally appending the data to the previously run stocks, creating a very large data frame.

I believe this is extremely inefficient, and have recently discovered creating a list of dataframes, which I believe will be much more efficient.  But I'm struggling to understand how to replicate the adding of a calculated SMA column to each row, of each dataframe in my list.  I think it requires the use of lapply, or one of the similar apply functions but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't properly understand your problem. If you want to add a column to all data frames in a list, you can do like this

```
List <- lapply(List,function(x) x$sma <- sma10;return(x))
```

A reproducible example will help

Comment: I apologize for my unclear question.  I tried to avoid asking it, mostly because I couldn't figure out the best way to word it, but you managed to grasp the main idea.  The only difference was that I was wanting to add this as a column to the existing list, but I believe I can use `cbind` to do that.  Thanks!